# Escaping backslash in a string containing backslash

Tags: javascript, backslash

I have a string containing `I\u2019m` (with backslashes not escaped)

```
var myString = 'I\\u2019m'; // I\u2019m
```

But then I need a function that 'escape backslashes' that string, so the function I'm looking for would return `I'm`

```
backslashString(myString); // I'm
```

I've tried using eval:

```
function backslashString(input){
   input = input.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); // Replace ' with \' that's going to mess up eval
   return eval(`'${input}'`);
}
```

But is there a proper way of doing it? I'm looking for a function that escape backslashes a string containing `I\u2019m` to `I'm` and also handles if there's an extra backslash (`A lost \ backslash`)

EDIT:
I did not ask what I meant from the start. This not only applies to unicode characters, but applies to all backslash characters including `\n`

Comment: _“People are misinterpreting the question”_ - more correct would be to say, you did not manage to ask what you actually _meant_ right from the start … this changes the context of the question quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for that tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no other way other than eval (JSON.parse doesn't like new lines in strings)
NOTE: The function would return false if it has a trailing backslash

```
function backslashString(input){
    input = input.replace(/`/g, '\\`'); // Escape quotes for input to eval
    try{
        return eval('`'+input+'`');
    }catch(e){ // Will return false if input has errors in backslashing
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse('"I\\u2019m"'));
```

OR for multiple

```
'I\\\u2019m'.split('\\').join().replace(/,/g,'');
'I\u2019m'.split('\\').join().replace(/,/g,'');
```

Comment: Not just in this I\u2019m case, but with others too

Comment: Edited again :)

Comment: Can you check it first, then post it? The string itself already escaped before `decodeURICompoent` even touched it, so you're technically inputting `I'm`. The proper way to test it is `decodeURIComponent('I\\u2019m')`, which doesn't work

Comment: What's the use of decodeURIComponent? And that's just the same as eval. I'm looking for a native function or a function that doesn't use these type of methods.

Comment: It takes the Unicode and converts it to its readable format, why make things difficult? use what is there to make life easier

Comment: What happens if there's an extra  quote, an extra backslash?

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes aren’t the real problem here - the real problem is the difference between *code* and *data*.

`\uXXXX` is JavaScript syntax to write the Unicode codepoint of a character in a text literal. It gets replaced with the actual character, when the JavaScript parser interprets this *code*.

Now you have a variable that contains the value `I\u2019m` already - that is *data*. This does not get parsed as JavaScript, so it does mean the literal characters `I\u2019m`, and not `I’m`. `eval` can “fix” that, because the missing step of interpreting this as code is simply what eval *does*.

If you do not want to use eval (and thereby invite all the potential risks that entails, if the input data is not completely under your control), then you can parse those numeric values from the string using regular expressions, and then use `String.formCharCode` to create the actual Unicode character from the given code point:

```js
var myString = 'I\\u2019m and I\\u2018m';

var myNewString = myString.replace(/\\u([0-9]+)/g, function(m, n) {
  return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n, 16)) }
);

console.log(myNewString)
```

`/\\u([0-9]+)/g` - regular expression to match this `\uXXXX` format (X=digits), `g` modifier to replace all matches instead of stopping after the first.

`parseInt(n, 16)` - to convert the hexadecimal value to a decimal first, because `String.fromCharCode` wants the latter.

Comment: What about `'\n'`?

Comment: What about it? Not sure what you are trying to ask now.

Comment: Your answer only applies to escape expressions like `/uNumber` but I’m more like looking for an answer that applies to all escape backslash expressions like `\n`, thanks though

Comment: There is no general built-in way to “translate” such escape sequences into the corresponding character - but the list of possible escape sequences is limited, so one could write a function that handles each case specifically. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation